# Spotipy Authorization Code Flow - Error when username has underscores

Tags: python-3.x, spotipy

I am using the Spotipy Python library to interact with the Spotify web API. One of the two flows for user authentication is [Authorization Code Flow](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#authorization-code-flow). I tried to run the code in the example from the terminal typing my username, which includes an underscore. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

scope = 'user-library-read'

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    username = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "Usage: %s username" % (sys.argv[0],)
    sys.exit()

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name']
else:
    print "Can't get token for", username
```

But it gives me the following traceback error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spotipy/util.py", line 56, in prompt_for_user_token
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_cached_token()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 135, in get_cached_token
    if 'scope' not in token_info or not self._is_scope_subset(self.scope, token_info['scope']):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 157, in _is_scope_subset
    haystack_scope = set(haystack_scope.split())
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'**

Then I tried the same code with other username without underscore and it worked. So the problem is related to splitting a string with an underscore. Any idea to solve this?